# How to run spell check on multiple files and display any incorrect words in shell script?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, vim

I have a few files I wish to spellcheck. Normally I would open these in `vim`, run `:set spell` and do the changes. It's really teadious to open files and manually check if I've misspelt any words since the last check, however.

Is there a way I can run a spell-check on a lot of files and display any incorrectly-spelt words found, along with the filename, so that I can go and change them? I don't want to open every file, check if it's "clean", then open the next and repeat.

I can't find any POSIX spellcheck utility. Some Red-Hat based Linux distributions allegedly have `spell` or similar, but I'd prefer a cross-platform(ish) method. I know `vim` *can* spellcheck - is there any way of spellchecking without doing it all manually? It'd be *fantastic* if I could shell-script a solution.

I'm running `OS X`, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can install aspell with Homebrew on OS X. `brew info aspell` lists supported languages.

```
brew install aspell --lang=en,fi,jp
```

`aspell check` opens a file in an interactive spell checker:

```
for f in *.txt; do aspell check $f; done
```

`aspell list` prints all unrecognized words:

```
cat *.txt | aspell list | sort -u
```

Learned words are stored in `.aspell.en.pws` by default. You can also exclude words in `~/Library/Spelling/en` after adding `personal_ws-1.1 en` as the first line.

```
aspell list --personal=$HOME/Library/Spelling/en
```

Answer (score 11):

Using [aspell](http://aspell.net/man-html/), this will print each filename then a sorted list of misspelled words together with the number of times they occur:

```
for f in *.txt ; do echo $f ; aspell list < $f | sort | uniq -c ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `find` command.  Doing so will work recursively and edit files in subdirectories too.

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec aspell check {} \;
```

Explanation:

- **`find`**: Find...
- **`.`**: in this directory
- **`-type f`**: files (not directories)
- **`-name "*.txt"`**: ending in .txt
- **`-exec aspell check {} \;`**: and run aspell on each of them.

The quoted wildcard is a bash construct.  It might not be POSIX-compliant.

Comment: aren't you missing a `{}` here? as in `find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec aspell check {} \;`

Comment: @kuropan Yeah looks like it.  Edited.